# Include custom css in Symfony project

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to include some custom CSS in my Symfony 2.7 project, but i can't get this working.

My CSS is located in `app/Resources/public/css/timeline.css`

Included this in my code `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('app/Resources/public/css/timeline.css') }}">`

And executed this command `app/console assets:install web --symlink`


What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `app/console assets:install web --symlink` install assets in web directory, and you are pointed in `app directory`.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html#using-assetic

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the best practices and put your css, js, images in the web directory and your codes will be OK

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/best_practices/web-assets.html)

This command `app/console assets:install web --symlink` creates a symbolink link to your assets in your `web` directory. You should try pointing your `assets` function to web instead of app.